# Is there an accepted way to plot a wave function and the potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, education

When using the time-independent Schrodinger equation and finding a wave function $\psi(x)$ for a given potential $V(x)$ is there a consistent way to plot these two objects on the same image that takes into account the differences in units and then gives you a visual way to see how various wave functions, e.g., with different eigenvalues $E_n$, behave in the same potential that is more meaningful than the "collages" that are floating around (see picture below)?

[image: wavefunction-potential-image]

Comment: This gives a false impression  ,  such plots are useful for tunneling explanations http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html  , the wavefunction should be falling within the barrier

Comment: Well, the requirement is that the *probability* is falling within the barrier, and the green curve actually agrees with that. So what we are talking about here is making the visualization *helpful*. I would either (a) choose the phase of each eigenfunction such that their tails all looked the same (which will make their slopes at $r=0$ alternate in sign) or (b) plot the probability rather than the wavefunction.